# How to free a dynamic allocated array from another function without making that array global?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, global-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2);    // prototype


char *newstring;    // global pointer

int main(){
    char string1[] = "test1";
    char string2[] = "test1";

    printf("Final string: %s\n", mystrcat(string1, string2));
    free(newstring);    // I'd like to free the array here, without using a global array
}

char *mystrcat(char *s1, const char *s2){

    unsigned int len1=0;
    while (*(s1+len1)!='\0') {  // to count lenght of first string
        len1+=1;
    }

    unsigned int len2 = 0;
    while (*(s2+len2)!='\0') {  // to count lenght of second string
        len2+=1;
    }

    newstring = calloc(len1+len2+1, sizeof(char));

    unsigned int i = 0;
    size_t main_count = 0;
    for (; main_count<len1; ++main_count, ++i){
        *(newstring+main_count) = *(s1+i);
    }
    i = 0;
    for (; main_count<len1+len2; ++main_count, ++i){
        *(newstring+main_count) = *(s2+i);
    }

    return newstring;
}
```

This is a program to concatenate two strings. The thing is that I am doing an exercise and I must use that prototype, and I can't change it, so I **can't** pass the array for reference. So how can I return the array to main and **then** free that array (in main) without using a global array outside main?

Comment: Do you know what function parameters are for?

Comment: You should use `size_t` for all index variables, not `unsigned int`, which may be a smaller type.

Comment: The first argument of `mystrcat` should also be defined as `const char *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already returning `newstring` from `mystrcat`, you simply need to store it in a variable.

```c
int main(){
    char string1[] = "test1";
    char string2[] = "test1";
    char* newstring = mystrcat(string1, string2);

    printf("Final string: %s\n", newstring);
    free(newstring);
}
```

Comment: So this will free the dynamically created array inside strcat function, right? Why does it tell me `warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' is invalid in C99` ?

Comment: Realize, memory created by ```malloc``` is not scoped to any function. It will exist until you free it. So, you can pass pointers to that memory around any which way you want, and the memory won't be affected.

Make sure you include ```stdlib.h```